# How to read MxM patches from an NxN image in tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am learning tensorflow and I don't know the idiomatic ways to manipulate tensors. I want to read a square matrix into overlapping patches, which would be used in a convolution.

If I have a simple square matrix, for example `np.arange(9).reshape((,3))`:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

What operation should I use to transform it by reading windows over it and give the following?

```
[[0 0 0] [0 0 1] [0 3 4]]
[[0 0 0] [0 1 2] [3 4 5]]
[[0 0 0] [1 2 0] [4 5 0]]
[[0 0 1] [0 3 4] [0 6 7]]
[[0 1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8]]
[[1 2 0] [4 5 0] [7 8 0]]
[[0 3 4] [0 6 7] [0 0 0]]
[[3 4 5] [6 7 8] [0 0 0]]
[[4 5 0] [7 8 0] [0 0 0]]
```

The numpy code I used is:

```
pad = 3

X = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
X_padded = np.pad(X, 3, mode='constant', constant_values=0)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        row_a = pad + i - pad // 2
        row_b = row_a + pad
        col_a = pad + j - pad // 2
        col_b = col_a + pad        
        print(X_padded[row_a:row_b, col_a:col_b])
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code is one way to achieve the desired process in TF.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
img = tf.constant([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
img = tf.reshape(img,[1,3,3,1])

op = tf.extract_image_patches(images=img, ksizes=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
op = tf.reshape(op,[-1,3,3,1])

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print("img")
    print(img.eval())
    result = sess.run(op)
    result = np.squeeze(result)
    print("result")
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
img
[[[[0][1][2]] 
  [[3][4][5]]
  [[6][7][8]]]]
result
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 1]
  [0 3 4]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [1 2 0]
  [4 5 0]]

 [[0 0 1]
  [0 3 4]
  [0 6 7]]

 [[0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]
  [6 7 8]]

 [[1 2 0]
  [4 5 0]
  [7 8 0]]

 [[0 3 4]
  [0 6 7]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[3 4 5]
  [6 7 8]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[4 5 0]
  [7 8 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: @Rdgstv, Did my answer help you ??